# Should a WAV audio file be twice size as an Audio Buffer?

Tags: type-conversion, wav, audiobuffer

I have a JS webaudio AudioBuffer which I convert to WAV using 3rd party code, and the length / size of WAV is always at least twice the size of the AudioBuffer.  As I am handling long duration audio (multi MB) its a potential issue.

My AudioBuffer is single channel (mono) and I have confirmed I am creating a mono WAV (where the library creates a stereo WAV, file size is 4x). I have tried using several solutions for the conversion but cannot get a WAV file of same size as AudioBuffer. I tried [Crunker](https://github.com/jackedgson/crunker), [audiobuffer-to-wav](https://github.com/Jam3/audiobuffer-to-wav), [this post](https://www.russellgood.com/how-to-convert-audiobuffer-to-audio-file/#render-as-wav).  With audiobuffer-to-wav I tried both 16 bit (2x) and 32 bit (4x).

Maybe it is not possible and due to audio data formats. But ideally I could get a WAV the same file size as AudioBuffer or even better a compressed MP3.

As context, I am feeding the WAV into an HTML audio element. I realise I can play audio direct with Web Audio, but have reasons to use an HTML audio element.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The AudioBuffer size you are getting is probably in samples, which are 16 bit or 32 bit when you convert them to WAV. If you can get 8 bit output the length will match (but the quality won't be very good).